# How do I install OSSIM (AlienVault SIEM) manually?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu-12.04

AlienVault by default is a .iso image. It installed on the core of Debian. I want to install it on Ubuntu 12.04. How can I do that?! Is it possible or not? (AlienVault is a SIEM product; it is an open-source monitoring security logs .., and is used in a Security Operations Center. I need to install it on Ubuntu. All the files of this product are in the pool directory of its Debian .iso image.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you cannot. OSSIM is an installable distribution. There are no individual packages. You can only install on bare system or in VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on VM or operating system. It can not be installed how you want it since it is not a package. If you are asking it having a specific network diagram at the back of your mind that needs to be changed since SIEM will be installed independently, but it can still integrate different operating solutions to itself even after.